# Consume Java Web Service with C#, error unable to generate temp class

Tags: java, c#, web-services, jagged-arrays

We are trying to consume a Java Web Service using C# and .Net framework 4.0 (also tried 2.0) and have run into a strange error of:

```
There was an error in serializing body of message userServiceAssignList1: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string[]' to 'string[][]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'string[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'string[]'
'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Googling around basically had turned up nothing as its a fairly common error with incorrectly coding strings and string arrays in C#.

The C# code is basically this, super simple where "localhost" is the web service or service reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    localhost.AdvancedBusinessTestIFClient abctic = new localhost.AdvancedBusinessTestIFClient();
    string[] services = {"Auto Attendant"};
    var resp = abctic.userServiceAssignList("echo", "SQA_P17615", services, null);

    Console.WriteLine(resp.ToString());
}
```

In researching, we found this similar issue:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AiPEIA0

So it looks to be a bug related to Microsofts serialization and wsgen as people have been complaining about it for more than 7 years now.  It appears to be related to a jagged array, e.g. a "string [][]".

The wsdl being consumed is a library written in java consisting of BroadSoft Broadworks classes generated using jax-b from their XSD files.  It is being hosted in a JBoss  EAP 7 aspplication server, Java 1.8.

Based on the salesforce link and the "string[][]" hint, we searched the Reference.cs file for "[][]" and sure enough found this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="C")]
public partial class OCITable : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string[] colHeadingField;

    private string[][] rowField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("colHeading", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string[] colHeading {
        get {
            return this.colHeadingField;
        }
        set {
            this.colHeadingField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("colHeading");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("col", typeof(string[][]), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("col", typeof(string[][]), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public string[][] row {
        get {
            return this.rowField;
        }
        set {
            this.rowField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("row");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `private string[][] rowField;`

It was being caused by this snippet of Java code:

```
public class OCITable {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> colHeading;
    protected List<OCITableRow> row;


public class OCITableRow {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> col;
```

So as we can see its a multi-dimensional List of a List.

The WSDL chunk looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="OCITable">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="colHeading" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="row" nillable="true" type="tns:OCITableRow"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="OCITableRow">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="col" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Back to the SalesForce link, it appears that other apps such as SoapUI and java applications have no issues with arrays of arrays or jagged arrays however C# .Net has had this issue for quite a while.

Comment: and what is the question? in its current state this is more of a bug report

Comment: @1blustone thanks for the comment!  It is indeed a bug report but the answer ends up providing a solution, I wanted to get this Q&A out here as we spent about a day researching and trying to find a workaround!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into a lot of problems with the above question, especially with the poor results being returned by google so we wanted to help any one else that might run into this issue in the future especially seeing as how we couldn't easily modify the java side of things as a lot of jax-b marshaling and un-marshaling was going on and being handled automatically.

The SalesForce link let us know what the problem was and this link proposed a possible solution:
[How can I fix the web reference proxy that Visual Studio generated to handle jagged arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424397/how-can-i-fix-the-web-reference-proxy-that-visual-studio-generated-to-handle-jag)

My .Net partner @lavilla began looking at implementing the above code change though we really hated to have to modify the resulting proxy code as any updates in the future would need to be re-implemented (a pre-build step however will help with this) and he ran across this interesting Stack Exchange Q&A: [C# Deserializing an XML with repeating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197889/c-sharp-deserializing-an-xml-with-repeating-tags) by @Synia.

Thank you @Synia for also running into the exact same problem though it would have been awesome if you had "BroadSoft" or "BroadWorks" in your question (could someone please add BroadSoft and BroadWorks as tags as I dont have enough points).  This was the exact solution that we were looking for, thank you @DBC for the answer and thorough explanation.

Modifying the Reference.cs code previously shown in the question to reflect exactly what @DBC recommended worked perfectly!